# celery control add_consumer giving Error: No nodes replied within time constraint

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I want to configure celery worker to consume only from a particular queue, 
I saw in celery docs that `control add_consumer` does exactly that.
Problem is when I try :
`celery control -A [App_name] add_consumer [queue_name] worker1.h%` 
it gives me error :

> Error: No nodes replied within time constraint

Any help is really appreciated. 
Is there any other way I can make my worker consume from a specific queue?

Note : `celery -A [App_name] worker1.h%`
starts the celery worker, and everything works fine just that is works on all my queues. I want to dedicate a worker to consume from specific queue.
Broker used: rabbitmq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just run a separate worker

```
celery -A app_name -Q queue_name --concurrency=1
```

Comment: I tried this, something weird happened here, it was getting attached to all queues which we use for our tasks.

Comment: sorry, that is very unclear. what is getting attached? how do you mean attached - the task is being run by all workers? if so you have a misconfiguration somewhere

Comment: So there is one task defined which has 2 steps, the steps consume from different queues, now when i configure a worker to consume from a queue in above fashion it should only execute 1 step but its not doing that. When i go and check consumers in the rabbitmq dashboard it shows that this worker is added as consumer to both the queues :(

Comment: if you want help with your problem please update your answer to show the command line used to run the workers and your celery configuration, plus the code of an simple example task which exhibits the problem

Comment: class OrderInfoConsumerStep(ConsumerStep):  
queue = Queue(settings.QUEUES)  
def get_consumers(self, channel):  
return [Consumer(channel, queues=[self.queue, ],  
callbacks=[self.handle_message, ], accept=['json', ])]  
def handle_message(self, body, message):  
data = json.loads(body)//storeData    
message.ack()   celery_app.steps['consumer'].add(OrderInfoConsumerStep)

Comment: But still i am not able to figure out how to start a worker which will consume from one queue only. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: the command I posted should do that. If it doesn't then please see my previous comments.

Comment: command should be `celery worker -A app -Q queue_name`. please include a minimal output from your log - at the top it should indicate what queues it is listening to. also are you sure you are routing your tasks properly. you really really need to update your question with all this information. otherwise you cannot be helped